# save part of json file after getJson

Tags: javascript, jquery, getjson

I am using GetJson to get a file and then I need the user to have the option to save part of it or open it , without putting the data on the server at any time.  How can I do this? I need it to work on IE8 up and mobile devices as well as firefox and chrome.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="data:application/octet-stream;charset=utf-8;base64,YOUR_FILE">Download</a>
```

Where `YOUR_FILE` is the string you want to appear inside the file, converted to base64 encoding. In the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VBJ9h/1032/) I'm providing, you have `bG9yZW0gaXBzdW0=` which once converted back to readable text, represents *Lorem ipsum*

However, I'm unsure as to the [support for Internet Explorer 8.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme#Web_browser_support)